# how to merge file lines having the same first word in python?

Tags: python, debugging, computer-science

I have written a program to merge lines in a file containing the same first word 
in python.However I am unable to get the desired output.
Can anyone please suggest me the mistake in my program?

**Note:- (line1,line 2)** and **(line4,line5,line6)** are merging since they 
have the same first element

```
#input
"file.txt"
line1: a b c
line2: a b1 c1
line3: d e f
line4: i j k
line5: i s t 
line6: i m n 

#output
a b c a b1 c1 
d e f
i j k i s t i m n 

#my code
for i in range(0,len(a)):
j=i
try:
    while True:
        if  a[j][0] == a[j+1][0]:
            L.append(a[j])
            L.append(a[j+1])
            j=j+2
        else:
            print a[i]
            print L
            break
except:
    pass`
```

Comment: what output do you want to get?

Comment: i want to merge the lines having the same first word.

Comment: how are they all joined, what is the common character in line2 and line3?

Comment: which word are you referring to?

Comment: the first word

`Eg:- **one** two three 
     **one** seven six
      three four five
OUTPUT:- 
     **one** two three **one** seven six
      three four five`

Comment: it is still unclear what you want, in your input txt file, what are your conditions for grouping? is line1: etc.. in your file or just for illustration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (give it the file as an argument).

Produces a dictionary with the lines you expect.

```
import sys
if "__main__" == __name__:


    new_lines = dict()
    # start reading file
    with open(sys.argv[1]) as a:

        # iterate file by lines - removing newlines
        for a_line in a.read().splitlines():

            # candidate is first word in every sentence
            candidate = a_line.split()[0] # split on whitespace by default

            # dictionary keys are previous candidates
            if candidate in new_lines.keys():

                # word already included
                old_line = new_lines[candidate]
                new_lines[candidate] = "%s %s" % (old_line, a_line)

            else:

                # word not included
                new_lines[candidate] = a_line


# now we have our dictionary. print it (or do what you want with it)
for key in new_lines.keys():
    print "%s -> %s" % (key, new_lines[key])
```

output:

```
a -> a b c a b1 c1
i -> i j k i s t i m n
d -> d e f
```

Comment: I am sorry but your program is not giving any output.

Comment: Try and save it under `program.py` and run it using this command: `python program.py file.txt` (assuming `file.txt` is where the input is).

More about sys.argv: http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/system/python-sys-argv

Comment: you don't need split(' '), it splits on whitespace by default.